The weak topology on a closed subspace coincides with the weak topology on the whole space restricted to the closed subspace
Let $X$ be a Banach space and $U \subseteq X$ a closed subspace.
Show that if we restrict $\sigma(X,X^*)$ to $U$ we get the weak topology on $U$.
My attempt:
I didn't really know how to start, so I wrote down the definitions first.
$X^*=\{f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{K}: \text{ f is continuous and linear }\}$
The topology $\sigma(X,X^*)$ is induced by $\mathcal{P}=\{p_f : f \in X^*\}$ where $p_f(x):=|f(x)|$ for $x \in X$.
The topology $\sigma(U,U^*)$ is induced by $\mathcal{P}_U=\{p_f : f \in U^*\}$ where $p_f(x):=|f(x)|$ for $x \in U$.
It is easy to see that if one restricts the seminorms in $\mathcal{P}$ to $U$ and $U^*$, we get $\mathcal{P}_U$. Thus $\sigma(X,X^*)_{|U} \subseteq \sigma(U,U^*)$.
I am struggling at the converse direction.
How do I show  $  \sigma(U,U^*) \subseteq \sigma(X,X^*)_{|U}$?

By a corollary of the Hahn-Banach theorem, any continuous functional $f\in U^*$ can be extended to a continuous functional $F\in X^*$ which has the same norm, so $F|_U=f$, hence a set $p_f^{-1}(O)$ in $\sigma(U,U^*)$, for some $f\in U^*$, $O\subseteq \mathbb{K}$, can be written as
$$p_f^{-1}(O)=\{x\in U:|f(x)|\in O\}=\{x\in U:|F|_U(x)|\in O\}=\{x\in X:|F(x)|\in O\}\cap U,
$$
which is in $\sigma(X,X^*)|_U$.
